# How to make expandable/collapsable ImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have many `textViews` on top of a `scrollView` and every `textView` has a custom button over it so that when user click that `textView` it should expand and when it click back then it should collapse to previous position.

what I'm thinking of doing is hide the `smallTextView` and show the `expandedTextView` when button is pressed and when the button is pressed i want to hide `expandedtextView` n show the `smallTextView`. but I don't know how I should do it. any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
-

 (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

            self.title = @"Demo";
            appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            for (int i=0;i<[appDelegate.serverResponseArray count];i++)
            {
            self.expandTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
            [self.expandTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, i*50.0f+10.0f, 270.0f, 40.0f)];
            [self.expandTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            [self.expandTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:12]];
            [self.expandTextView setText:@"Welcome!!!"];
            [self.expandTextView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
            [self.expandTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.expandTextView];
            self.expandTextView = nil;

            self.expandButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, i*50.0f+1.0f, 270.0f, 60.0f)];
            [self.expandButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [self.expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(textButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.expandButton.tag = i;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.expandButton];

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(278.0f, i*50.0f+10.0f, 14.0f, 40.0f)];
            [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
            imageView = nil;

        }


        float maxHeight = 0;

            for(UIView *v in [self.scrollView subviews])
            {
                if(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height > maxHeight)
                    maxHeight = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height;
            }

            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, maxHeight+2570);

        }
        -(IBAction)textButtonClicked:(id)sender
        {
             NSLog(@"%@",sender);
        }
```

[image: in this image every imageView has a custom button over it]
and how do I know which button is getting pressed.

Comment: It should be Table View, not Image View.

Comment: that imageview should be a tableview or a uiview ...

Comment: these aren't the table View coz i dont know how make tableView expandable and these aren't the imageView either. these are textViews.

Answer (score 0):

To know which button press you have to assign tag value to your button then

```
-(IBAction)textButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;

    NSLog(@"Tag of button = %d",btn.tag);
}
```

And i suggest you to change frame of your existing imageView instead of using other image view(hide and show)

Comment: i edited my question, these are textView and i have assigned tag value to my buttons in `viewDidLoad`. if u see this line `self.expandButton.tag = i;` . And even the changing the frame size will work for me. can u guide lil more on that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I'd suggest you to use `UITableView` instead of `UIImageView` and then implement Expandable and Collapsible `UITableViewCell`.

There are lots of Tutorial to implement this Functionality. Simply Google it and you will have plenty of solutions for that.

For Example : [Expandable/Collapsible Table For iOS](http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/)

Check this Sample Code provided by Apple : [Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: my actual problem is i need to make an expandable/collapsable View. And i expandable View i need to have lot of lables and textViews. is it possible by using tableView that if i expand tableView and in that expanded view i can have labels or textView or anything.

Comment: @Zac24: `UITableViewCell` is also a kind of `UIView`. So, you can implement it with `UITableView`. Just check the links provided by me.

Comment: i checked the first link provided by you.

Comment: @Zac24: so, did you get your Answer ?

Comment: not yet exactly. i don't know why m thinking that doing in my way (i mean hiding and showing the textView) will be lot easier. I'm newbie so u can tell better.

Comment: @Zac24: This is easier too. Check the links given by me. Read it all. What you are thinking is not the legal way. Use Table View.

Comment: okay. i'll get back to this problem soon but for time being i found another way doing things, not doing expandable/collapsable View for now.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is Take UITableView and Put your images on Cell of UITableView and change size of cell when your click on it, i give you simple example for how to create expandable UITableViewCell.

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/